# Notation for the domain of $f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)$?

Tags: analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

I have two vectors, $\mathbf x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbf y \in \mathbb R^m$ and the real-valued function
$$
f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=f(x_1,\dots, x_n, y_1, \dots y_m)
$$
Is the domain $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m=\mathbb R^{n+m}$ or $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m=\mathbb R^{n m}$?

Comment: This site prefers not to leave answered questions marked unanswered. If you feel that your question has been answered, please consider accepting one of the answers by clicking the check mark (✓).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\mathbb R^N$ consists of $N$-tuples of real numbers. That is, an element in $\mathbb R^N$ is built from $N$ real numbers.

Clearly, your function has $N  = n+m$ and not $nm$ real numbers as input, hence it cannot be $\mathbb R^{nm}$, but it is $$\mathbb R^{n}\times \mathbb R^{m} = \mathbb R ^{n+m}.$$

Comment: Thanks! For the case $m=n$ is it correct to write $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^{n+n}=\mathbb R^{2n}$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe Yes, that would be correct. Just think of ordinary numbers $a^n\cdot a^m = a^{n+m}$ and $a^n\cdot a^n = a^{n+n} = a^{2n}.$

Answer (score 1):

The domain is $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m:$  the easiest way to this about this is that $f$ depends on $m + n$ variables.